# Validating request coming from the client side of a JDBC server

Tags: database, jdbc, performance-testing, load-testing, client-side-validation

I have to implement a scenario, where a user logs in to the application and I have to validate the queries that where being executed during the load run of the log in scenario. Now I know that the JDBC sampler allows to run certain queries and returns their response but that is not needed here. I want to check that when a number of users Login to the application, exactly what queries have been initiated. A road map or associated tool will be very helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if there is an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) in place as well-behaved APM tools can show the SQL queries associated with the HTTP requests.

If it's not there you can only get the query log from the database, depending on the database type you can either use the aforementioned [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler or if the database doesn't expose its query logs via SQL you may need to go to the database server directly and get the query log via command-line using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)